# Example uses queryset instead of model attribute for a DetailView extending class

Tags: python, django

On the django docs page the method `get_object` is explained for the `DetailView` class. They are using this code snippet as an example:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Author
class AuthorDetailView(DetailView):

    queryset = Author.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        # Record the last accessed date
        obj.last_accessed = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

[Here's the link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).
What I don't understand is why `queryset` attribute is used and why they are loading all objects of the Author from the database. Shouldn't the code be

`model = Author.objects.get(pk=self.pk) ?`

Considering it's not a ListView but a detail view

Comment: This is done in the `super().get_object()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then what is the use of the line  ` queryset = Author.objects.all()` ? Why did they include this?

Comment: because they need a "base queryset" to start doing filtering.

Comment: filtering for what? The pk? cant they just use Author.objects.get(pk=self.pk)  to filter for that?

Comment: or is it simply to tell django what class must be used for the detail view? here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/ they say the queryset attribute can be used to indicate what model to use, but then i still find it strange that they don't just use `model`  instead since it would be more appropiate for a DetailView

Comment: by default it will look if there is a `pk` and/or `slug` parameter in the path, and then indeed filter on these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short**: the `super().get_object()` will properly perform a `.get()` on the `queryset` attribute.

> Shouldn't the code be `model = Author.objects.get(pk=self.pk)`? Considering it's not a `ListView` but a `DetailView`.

This *is* done. The standard `get_object()` method of the `SingleObjectMixin` will filter the `queryset` you defined with a primary key and/or slug, and return that object. You can inspect this method in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/detail.py#L20-L56). Although the real method is a bit more complicated (since you can configure the name of the `pk` and `slug` field), it basically boils down to:

```
# oversimplified version!

class SingleObjectMixin(ContextMixin):
    # …

    def get_object(self, queryset):
        return self.get_queryset().get(
            pk=self.kwargs['pk'],
            slug=self.kwargs['slug']
        )
```

So what you here do is make a `super().get_object()` call that will do the proper filtering of the `queryset`, and then make some modifications to the object retrieved by that `get_object()` method.

> why they are loading all objects of the Author from the database.

They are *not* loading any `Author` objects at all. `QuerySet`s are lazy. This means that as long as you do not "consume" the queryset, it will not make a query to the database. By using `.get(..)` you will make a query, but only one with the filters, so retrieve (normally) one record.

Comment: This website is excellent for understanding the details of how CBVs work, and how to override them.  https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Comment: Also, `why they are loading all objects of the Author from the database`, remember that this isn't actually happening in this line `queryset = Author.objects.all()`, the queryset is only evaluated (i.e. loaded from database) when the objects are actually needed, so when the `queryset` is filtered inside `get_object`, the objects weren't loaded yet, its just creating a SQL query. The only loaded object will be the result

Comment: @LucasAbbade: well I did not spot that part in the question. Updated now :)